# array element attribute is undefined when using props in Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use Prop in Vue to pass an array to a child component.
Somehow, I am able to get access all of the variables and their properties except for one of them, maxAmt. I heard that this may be due to how we use camelCase vs camel-case, but after changing the variable attribute names, nothing has worked. Here is my code:

Edit: just to clarify, i am able to acess and display the `maxAmt` in the parent component, but not in the child component.

parent component:

```html
<script>
import database from '../firebase.js'
export default {
  
  data(){
    return{
      grantsList:[]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    fetchItems:function(){
      database.collection('Grants').get().then((querySnapShot)=>{
        querySnapShot.forEach(doc=>{
            let grant={}
            doc=doc.data()
            grant.name=doc.Name
            grant.grantInfo = doc.GrantInfo
            grant.maxamt = doc.maxAmt // PROBLEM VARIABLE
            grant.grantAmount = doc.GrantAmount
            grant.detail = doc.Detail
            grant.apply = doc.Apply
            console.log(grant)
            //console.log(grant.maxAmt)
            grant.show=false
            this.grantsList.push(grant)      
        })
      })
    },
    open:function(link){
      window.open(link)
    }
    },
    created(){
    this.fetchItems()
    
  }  
}
</script>
```

child component:

```html
<script>
export default {
    props:{
        grantsList:{
            Type:Array
        }
    },
    data(){
        return {
            x: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getTotal(){
            var sum = 'hi'
            this.grantsList.forEach(g => {
                //console.log(g.amount) // correct output
                console.log(g.maxamt) // THIS PART IS UNDEFINED
                sum += g.amount
            });
            console.log(sum)
            this.x = sum
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Using console.log(g.maxamt), i see `undefined`, but the other variables are somehow showing so im really confused as to how only one attribute is unable to be displayed.

Comment: `doc.maxAmt` ... looking at the other variables ... could it be you need `doc.MaxAmt` - i.e. PascalCase not camelCase? - since ALL the other `doc` properties are PascalCase not camelCase

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. `doc.maxAmt` was named in that way just because that was what i put as the name in my firebase. To check, i actually created another MaxAmt attribute. Using console.log to check it still outputs `undefined`. Also, just to clarify, i am able to display the `grant.maxamt` in my Parent component but NOT my child component

Comment: `i am able to display the grant.maxamt` ... is that maxamt or maxAmt? since your code has a commented `console.log(grant.maxAmt)` not `console.log(grant.maxamt)`

Comment: `grant.maxAmt` was a previous renaming of the variable. Basically, in the parent component, i am able to display the `doc.maxAmt` using whatever grant.(insert any name here).

My main issue is why i am not able to reuse the grant.(any name here) in the child component

Comment: so, `console.log(doc.maxAmt)` is fine? note: **doc.maxAmt** ... also, I just noticed you state that `g.amount` is correct ... yet nowhere else in your code do you have a property name `amount` - I think you may have confused yourself with the different amounts/amts/camel/pascal case etc ... step back ... take a deep breath ... and really check your code

Comment: Of wow you are right sorry i didn't see that. I just realised there is a different component with the same array name of GrantsList. Sorry for the dumb mistake...